# WooCommerce Get All Products as ID name pair

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using this function to get all products as ID name pairs to populate data into a select box.

```
    function get_product_list_as_key_name(){
                    $args     = array( 'post_type' => 'product','posts_per_page' => -1);
                    $products = get_posts( $args );
                    $products_list = array();
                    if(!empty($products)){
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach ($products as $value) {
                            $products_list[$i]['id'] = $value->ID;
                            $products_list[$i]['name'] = strlen($value->post_title) > 25 ? substr(strip_tags($value->post_title), 0, 25) . "..." : $value->post_title;
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }
        return $products_list;
    }
```

Is there any better way to do this?(Any default function ?)

Answer (score 0):

No you have to do this manually. or you can do this with custom query

```
    function get_product_list_as_key_name(){
        global $wpdb;
        $query = "SELECT ID,post_title FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts where post_type='product' AND post_status='publish'";
        $products_array = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $query ) );
        return $products_array;
    }
```

this is more fast then yours.

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(),
Notice: wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly